# JAVA FX set window/stage on front of OSX Dock

Tags: macos, netbeans, javafx, osx-yosemite

I can't get a JAVA FX "FXML" window to get on front of the OSX Dock on Yosemite 10.10.1.

I created a fresh  "new JavaFX FXML-enabled application" on NetBeans which gives this code :

```
public class Test extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
       Scene scene = new Scene(root);
       stage.setScene(scene);
       stage.show();
       stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true); // I ADDED THIS
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
     }   
}
```

I added `setAlwaysOnTop()` on my stage, but still, my window is always hidden behind the dock.

[image: Window at the left bottom]

Is there a way to set my window on front ?

Answer (score -1):

Add these lines as well lets see it helps:

```
 Rectangle2D primScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
 stage.setX((primScreenBounds.getWidth() - stage.getWidth()) / 2);
 stage.setY((primScreenBounds.getHeight() - stage.getHeight()) / 2);
```

This code should put your stage in the center of your screen.

So:

```
public class Test extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
   Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
   Scene scene = new Scene(root);
   stage.setScene(scene);
   Rectangle2D primScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
   stage.setX((primScreenBounds.getWidth() - stage.getWidth()) / 2);
   stage.setY((primScreenBounds.getHeight() - stage.getHeight()) / 2);
   stage.show();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   launch(args);
 }
```

}